# Balloon out of gas but won't accept fuel

Tags: mad-max

So several times now I go to refuel a balloon but I don't have the option of pouring in the fuel when I'm at the funnel unit (in particular, Wailing Wind and Rot 'N' Rusties territories). Even when I come back, I have to bring my own fuel and the container still won't accept my refueling (yes, I'm positive the balloon is still out of fuel and can't rise).

Comment: Ok, I'm buying this game...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this same issue....What you actually need to do here is go to the balloon itself with a fuel tank and add gas to it there. There is a small gas tank on the side of the balloon which it gets the gas from...not very obvious, but it is there.

Comment: it took me 3 tries at this before I got mad and went to the balloon...the thing we were trying to add gas to before is the wench for the balloon I believe.